# The integration has two answers $\int \cot(x)*\csc^2 (x)$, which one is correct in the definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

When you integrate $\int \cot \theta \csc^2 \theta d \theta$ it has two answers.

Using simple substitution you can solve like this:

$u=\cot \theta$, $du=-\csc^2 \theta d \theta$

$\int - u du=-\frac{u^2}{2}+C=-\frac{\cot^2 \theta}{2}+C$

However, if you apply trigonometical identities and express the integral like this: $\int \cot \theta \csc^2 \theta d \theta=\int \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin^3 \theta}d \theta$

You then can clearly use simple substitution to solve this but in a different way:

$u=\sin \theta$, $du=\cos \theta d \theta$

$\int \frac{du}{u^3}=-\frac{1}{2u^2}+C=-\frac{1}{2\sin^2 \theta}+C=-\frac{1}{2}\csc^2 \theta + C$

Now, when the integral is indefinite, both answers are exactly the same because of the trigonometrical identity: $\cot^2 \theta + 1 =\csc^2 \theta$. However, when the integral is definite from a point $a$ to a point $b$: $\int_a ^b \cot \theta \csc^2 \theta d \theta$. It gives two different answers.

So, what is the correct answer to the definite integral?

Comment: No, the two antiderivatives do _not_ give two different answers to the definite integral.

Comment: As David pointed out, the definite integral are the same. When you evaluate $\int_a^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$, if you replace $F$ with $F+c$, with $c$ constant, then the constant cancels.

Comment: You are right... Fail